# Navigation bar is not showing in iPad

Tags: ios

I am creating universal app,when I run the app in simulator(iPhone) navigation bar is showing but when I run it using simulator(iPad) navigation bar is not showing.Please anyone can tell me why this happening...I don't have any idea about this..
Here is my code.

```
     if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

          ObjNewFeedVC = [[newFeedsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"newFeedsViewController" bundle:nil];
          ObjSecondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

          }
          else{

          ObjNewFeedVC = [[newFeedsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"newFeedsViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
          ObjSecondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

              }


  objNavController1 = [[UINavigationController   alloc]initWithRootViewController:ObjNewFeedVC];
            objNavController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:ObjSecondVC];



            tabBarObj = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
            tabBarObj.viewControllers = @[objNavController1,objNavController2];
            self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


            [self.window addSubview:tabBarObj.view];
```

Comment: How are you creating your View?  XIB or Programmaticaly ?

Comment: @Vinay Jain  using XIB

Comment: use this, set window root view as `UITabBarController` remove this  `[self.window addSubview:tabBarObj.view];` and use this   `self.window.rootViewController = tabBarObj;`

Comment: still not working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simulator(iPad) don't show navigation bar, 
Run your app on real device(iPad) then it will show navigation bar...